# Why is sequential file naming not working?

Tags: java

I am trying to solve [this question](https://code.dcoder.tech/challenges/5b759daa791e284892a42c4e/sequential-naming).

---

**Problem Statement**

You are developing a File Manager but encountered a problem. You realised that two files cannot have the same names and if a conflict arises, the file which came later has to be appended with a number `N` such that `N` is the smallest positive number that is not used with that particular file name. The number is append in the form of `file_name(N)`. Write a code to solve your problem. You will be given an array of strings of file names. You need to assume that if a file name appears earlier in an array, it was created first.
**NOTE:** `file_name` and `file_name(2)` are two different file names i.e if a file name already has a number appended to it, its a different file name.

**Input**
The first line contains `N`, the number of strings.
The next line contains `N` space-separated strings (file names).

**Output**
Print the names of files, after making the necessary changes separated by space.

**Constraints**

> 1 ≤ N ≤ 50
> 1 ≤ file_name.length ≤ 25
> filename has no white space characters

**Sample Input**

```
7
file sample sample file file file(1) file(1)
```

**Sample Output**

```
file sample sample(1) file(1) file(2) file(1)(1) file(1)(2)
```

---

Below is my code. When I tested it with my own file names, it renames well but when I submit it, the tests fail. I would like to know what's wrong with my code and why its not working.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Dcoder {
  public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

    // Read number of file names and create
    // an array to hold them
    String[] fileNames = new String[scanner.nextInt ()];

    // Fill the array with the supplied names
    // from System.in
    for (int i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++)
      fileNames [i] = scanner.next ();

    // Modify the file names
    for (String fileName : fileNames) {
      int count = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++)
        if (fileName.equals (fileNames [i])) {
          fileNames [i] = fileNames [i] + (count == 0 ? "" : "(" + count + ")");
          count++;
        }
    }

    // Print out the modified list of file names
    for (String fileName : fileNames)
      System.out.print (" " + fileName);
  }
}
```

Comment: What test(s) fail? What's the issue?

Comment: The problem is that the modified `fileName` is written-back into the input array. So if we have an array with content `["a", "a", "a"]` , the 1st `"a"` stays as-is, the 2nd `"a"` is replaced by `"a(1)"`. Then, when the 3rd `"a"` is visited, we count the occurences of String `"a"` in the array up to the index of the last `"a"` (exclusive). Since the array contains the `String "a"` only once, the 3rd `"a"` is replaced with `"a(1)"` instead of `"a(2)"`.

Comment: @Turing85 Thank you for your feedback but I have input ` a a a` and the output was `a a(1) a(2)`. That may not be the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If all tests fail, then it is likely because your output has a space before the first name.

  The output should be the file name, space-*separated*, not space-*prefixed*.
- If you try input `"file file(1) file file"`, your code outputs

  ```
   file file(1) file(1)(1) file(2)
  ```

  but correct output is

  ```
  file file(1) file(2) file(3)
  ```

For better performance, you should use a `Set`.

```java
static void printUnique(String... fileNames) {
    Set<String> used = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++) {
        String newName = fileNames[i];
        for (int j = 1; ! used.add(newName); j++)
            newName = fileNames[i] + "(" + j + ")";
        if (i != 0)
            System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.print(newName);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

*Test*

```java
printUnique("file", "sample", "sample", "file", "file", "file(1)", "file(1)");
printUnique("file", "file(1)", "file", "file");
```

*Output*

```
file sample sample(1) file(1) file(2) file(1)(1) file(1)(2)
file file(1) file(2) file(3)
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried omitting spaces buts it still failed, but your code worked..thanks

Comment: Would you please also help me make my option work, when I removed extra spaces in my output, only one test passed, but others failed. Your code worked but I would also like your help in making my original code work

Comment: @Jore Your logic is flawed and you lose required information. That is why I wrote the logic differently.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is a *procedural approach* to the Problem.

Procedural approaches are not bad on their own.
But Java is an *Object Oriented* programming language and if you want to become a good Java programmer you should start looking for more OO-like solutions.

But OOP doesn't mean to "split up" code into random classes.

The ultimate goal of OOP is to reduce code duplication, improve readability and support reuse as well as extending the code.

Doing OOP means that you follow certain principles which are (among others):

- information hiding / encapsulation
- single responsibility
- separation of concerns
- KISS (Keep it simple (and) stupid.)
- DRY (Don't repeat yourself.)
- "Tell! Don't ask."
- Law of demeter ("Don't talk to strangers!")

#### So what could a more OO-like approach look like?

The underlaying question of that problem is: *"How often does a specific file name appear in the input?"* We want to find an association between *Strings* (file Names) and *integer values* (number of occurrence). This could be represented as a `Map<String,Integer>`. The whole logic is as simple as looking in the output if the current fileName already exists there and if so add the counter suffix. This means we need another `Collection` to hold the output.

My Solution would look like this:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class FileNameCounter {

    public List<String> renameDoubledFiles(List<String> input) {
        Map<String, Integer> occurrencesOfNames = new HashMap<>();
        LinkedList<String> output = new LinkedList<>();
        for (String fileName : input) {
            if (output.contains(fileName)) {
                Integer counter = updateCountFor(fileName, occurrencesOfNames);
                String suffixedName = appendCounterSuffix(fileName, counter);
                output.add(suffixedName);
            } else {
                output.add(fileName);
            }
        }
        return output;
    }

    private Integer updateCountFor(String fileName, Map<String, Integer> occurrencesOfNames) {
        Integer counter = occurrencesOfNames.getOrDefault(fileName, Integer.valueOf(0));
        occurrencesOfNames.put(fileName, ++counter);
        return counter;
    }

    private String appendCounterSuffix(String fileName, Integer counter) {
        return String.format("%s(%d)", fileName, counter);
    }

}
```

and here is the JUnit test to prove that it works:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class FileNameCounterTest {

    @Test
    void test() {
        List<String> input = Arrays.asList("file sample sample file file file(1) file(1)".split(" "));
        List<String> renamedDoubledFiles = new FileNameCounter().renameDoubledFiles(input);
        String output = renamedDoubledFiles.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
        assertEquals("file sample sample(1) file(1) file(2) file(1)(1) file(1)(2)", output);

    }

}
```